# How to debug remote program running on linux from windows

Tags: c++, linux, remote-debugging

I am used to visual studio debugger(its really good) and I have to debug a program running on linux(in C++) from my windows machine. Can anyone suggest how to debug remote program running on linux from windows

Comment: You need a debugger that will run on win and on linux, not sure if that exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install an X-Windows server on your windows machine, there are quite a few alternatives (e.g. cygwin/X).
- SSH to the linux machine with X forwarding enabled, or setup your X server to accept connections from your linux machine and manually setup the DISPLAY on the linux machine.
- Install and run e.g. `ddd` on the linux machine - it'll display on your windows machine
- debug

Answer (score 0):

For console based programs, you're going to want to look into [gbd](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gdb/). It's a command line utility, but with a bit of knowhow, it's every bit as capable as Visual Studio for tracking down a problem. You could start your program over a remote SSH session and debug it this way. This might even work for GUI based applications that you were viewing over a VNC connection.